How to Display Page Number on PDF generated by wkhtmltopdf in Laravel PHP?
I'm using Laravel PHP framework along with wkhtmltopdf to generate PDF documents from HTML. Everything works smoothly, but I'm struggling to display page numbers on the generated PDF. I've searched through the documentation and various forums but couldn't find a clear solution.
How to do page numbering in header/footer htmls with wkhtmltopdf? i tried this but i got this instead , (The process has been signaled with signal "11")

How are you generating the pdf? Show some code. Do you use a class like mikehaertl\wkhtmlto or call the binary directly?

$pdf = \PDF::setPaper('A4' ,'portrait')->setOptions(['header-right' => 'Page [page]'])
->loadView('pdf/generic-report-pdf', compact('supplier', 'data', 'request', 'sectionSums', 'params'));
    return $this->download($pdf->output(), $reportConfig->name . '-' . date('Y-m-d_H:i') . '.pdf');


Add that code to your question please and use formatting
